# How to use python for detecting if Windows has Windows Updates ready to install? in windows 10

Tags: python, windows-10

Is there any library to do this in python . I couldn't find any relevant answer for this.

Comment: This was posted to codereview a while back, but since COM doesn't really change, it may be useful in your case. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/135648/find-installed-and-available-windows-updates

Comment: This question belongs on the Software Recommendations SE (after it has been improved).